# DB2 SQL query on member file returns hex values

Tags: db2, hex, ibm-midrange, member

I am using Squirrel SQL client with the ODBC driver to connect to the DB2 database, which has no issues in extracting data from the db tables.

I want to extract data from a member file, and have created the alias, and executed the query:

```
CREATE ALIAS MFXFER.I316_E157324133 FOR MFXFER.GIK316BKP ("E157324133");

SELECT * FROM MFXFER.I316_E157324133;

DROP ALIAS IF EXISTS MFXFER.I316_E157324133;
```

When I execute the query the returned data is made up of only hex pairs (snippet line 1):

```
2  f1  f0  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  f8  f6  f2  f0  f2  f3  f0  f6  f0  f6  f0  f1  f0  f0  f0  f0  f0  f1  f0  f1  f1  f2  f6  f4  f5  f3  f6  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  e5  d6  60  c2  f3  60  f0  f2  f4  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  f2  f0  f2  f3  f0  f6  f0  f6  40  40  40  40  e2  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40  40
```

This does not reflect the ASCII values I can see in the member, when I view the same using RDi (Rational Developer for i).

[image: Contents of same member file]

When I copy and paste the hex to a translation tool, I receive only special characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the file has been created with CCSID 65535, data from this file are  considered binary data by the driver.

Don't forget IBMi is a EBCDIC platform, so converters have to know about EBCDIC like [this one](http://mcraigweaver.com/ebcdic.htm)

The RDi driver is probably configured to translate all binary/ccsid 65535 data.

So you have to either set driver property *translate binary* to true in SQuirreL SQL (if you use JT400 JDBC driver) or cast the column using

```
SELECT cast(GIK316BKP as char(nnn) ccsid ccc) as GIK316BKP FROM MFXFER.I316_E157324133
```

Comment: Note that ACS uses JDBC same as Squirrel and that ACS doesn't default to translating CCSID 65535; the ACS setting was changed by the user after install.

Comment: @Charles Yes and I verified it is not set by default in RDi either, while it is using DBeaver.

Comment: Thanks [nfgl],
I setup the appropriate CCSID value and I am now retrieving the data as expected.
Very much obliged.